# How can I get something close under a Commutative Diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xymatrix

I am trying to make a nice commutative diagram. I wrote it with xymatrix but it also works with tikZ. I want the distance between the diagram and the last line to be smaller. I have no idea how to do this.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

    \usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{xypic,amsmath}

    \begin{document}


   \begin{align*}
    \xymatrix{
    A \ar[r]^{x} \ar[d]^{\wr} & B\ar[d]^{\wr} \\    
            C \ar[r] & D\\
            (t \ar@{|->}[r]& z.
        }
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

A solution with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \ar[r, "x"] \ar[d, "\wr"] & B\ar[d, "\wr"] \\[4pt]
        C \ar[r] & D \\[-12pt]
        (t \ar[mapsto,r]& z).\\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Probably the easiest way is to reduce all row heights and then add an empty row in the square:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \xymatrix@R=.5pc{
    A \ar[r]^{x} \ar[dd]^{\wr} & B\ar[dd]^{\wr} \\ &\\
  C \ar[r] & D \\
  (t \ar@{|->}[r]& z).}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```